# Generic Compare throws "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Tags: c#, generics, icomparable

My Fancy Field Updater throws.

```
    public static bool UpdateField<T>(ref T target, T value)
    {
        bool updated;
        if (0 != Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(target, value))
        {
            target = value;
            updated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            updated = false;
        }
        return updated;
    }
```

I use this Updater for 'Value Types', System 'Reference Types' and my own 'Reference Types'. My types do not implement IComparable and I don't intend to do so. In those cases it is usually acceptable to just compare the references.

The point is that I want to be able to us it for anything. Is there a different implementation that would allow me to do so or do I have to catch the exception and try to handle those cases differently?

Comment: What makes a given reference greater than or less than another reference?

Comment: As an aside, putting the constant on the LHS of comparison operators is unconventional for C#.

Comment: Seems like you want to check Equality (equal or not equal) instead of comparing (greater than, less than, equal to).  So why not just use `target.Equals(value)` instead and rely on that being overwritten for value comparisons.

Comment: @Servy For references I would just update if not equal. I am not doing that per default because for value types I want to compare the values and not their references.

Comment: @juharr Yes, comparing equality is my usecase. I use the information if an update happened to decide elsewhere. target.Equals(value) would throw if target is null. Would Object.Equals do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't really want to compare the values in terms of "greater than or less than" - but for equality. So you should use `EqualityComparer.Default`:

```
public static bool UpdateField<T>(ref T target, T value)
{
    bool updated = !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(target, value);
    if (updated)
    {
        target = value;
    }
    return updated;
}
```

The default equality comparer does what you want for classes - it compares references for identity if the type doesn't either implement `IEquatable<T>` or override `object.Equals`.

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason to prefer this over `!target.Equals(value)`?

Comment: @juharr: Yes: if the type implements `IEquatable<T>`, the default equality comparer will invoke that directly. In particular, that avoids boxing when you're using value types.

Comment: @juharr Additionally that code will throw a NRE if `target` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if two values are equal using Comparer which is used to compare two values (sorting , greater than, less than and equal). Instead, use:

```
bool areEqual = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(target, value);
```

> IComparer interface supports ordering comparisons. That is, when the
>   Compare method returns 0, it means that two objects sort the same.
>   **Implementation of exact equality comparisons is provided by the**
>   **IEqualityComparer generic interface.**

Answer (score -3):

IComparable is an interface that lets YOU (the developer) determine if two objects, for purposes of your application, should be treated as "equal".  You might be a little less resistant to using the interface, friend, as it facilitates the work that you have to do and doesn't require that you generate external methods to compare your objects.  The try-catch approach will work, but it's crude and you'll end up cutting and pasting it all over your code.

Think MAINTAINABILITY.

Comment: Value types do implement that interface and it's for more than just checking equality as it will also tell you if one object is greater than or less than another.

Comment: `IComparable is obvious not for value types.`  This is just false. There are lots of value types that are comparable.  `it is an interface that lets YOU determine if two objects [...] should be treated as "equal".` No again, it lets you determine whether a given object is greater than, less than, or equal to another object.  `IEquatable` is used for an object to determine if it's equal to another object.

Comment: I am more than glad to retract my statement about this interface and value types.  But I think my *ahem* downvoters are missing the point.  Try-catch is not, in the long run, maintainable.

Comment: Well your first statement is still incorrect: "IComparable is an interface that lets YOU (the developer) determine if two objects, for purposes of your application, should be treated as "equal". " It's not for determining ordering. In rare cases, objects may be equal but still ordered one way or another.

Comment: And why would using try-catch in this method result in _cutting and pasting it all over your code_?

Comment: Webster's. Simple Definition of compare

: to look at (two or more things) closely in order to see what is similar or different about them

Comment: @juharr Because if another portion of code - say, in a different assembly - needed to compare two instances, you'd have to construct the whole try-catch hierarchy (or call a library function) in each place the comparison.  By using the interface, the comparison mechanism is embedded *within* the class instead of *externally*.

Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @codenoir: Well it certainly doesn't find "what is similar or different about them". Your definition is *simply wrong* - you're defining `IEquatable<T>` instead of `IComparable<T>`. MSDN is a rather better reference than a dictionary for this...